# Consider a scenario where I have setup autopay. In case I want to edit the settings, what should the ideal behaviour be? Should it load an empty form?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, settings, behavior-design

In such a case should the "Edit" button lead to an empty form or should it show the form with populated fields based on their previous settings?

Answer (score 1):

In this autopay scenario, the ideal behaviour would be to show the form with the current populated fields based on what the user had set previously.

This way the user can just make changes to the fields that they would like to change, instead of filling in all the details again.

Here are some additional references that might be helpful:
https://mikeknoop.com/ux-analysis-credit-card-form-ui-ideas/

Comment: Thanks, Michael!

Comment: No problem Rashmi, if my answer helped please mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks!